# Moving from Glype to Squid

Tags: javascript, proxy, frame, code-injection, postmessage

I have a website that uses Glype proxy. I use Glype to display remote websites in a frame. I started using Glype because I needed a way to "speak" to the frame website and determine it's size. To accomplish this I use DOM's window.postMessage. I inject the frame website with a script and then I can communicate.

I recently added Squid proxy into this whole thing. Right now I use it purely for caching means. Glype receives the content of all of the websites through Squid.

Is there any way to remove Glype completely out of this, and just use Squid? To be more specific:

How can I load frame content through Squid?
What would be the most appropriate way to inject a script into the frame website, using Squid?

By the way, as I mentioned in the beginning. The script injection that I use is purely for determining website's size. Nothing else. No evil in this thread.

The reason why I want to drop Glype is because, as good as it is, it often doesn't display pages properly.

Thanks!

Comment: how did you get glype to talk to squid?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Glype on the stated setup does not "talk" to Squid. The "talk to" reference is about frame communication. You can have your own website and within that website, a frame. The only way to communicate between the frame and the main page is to use window.postMessage, or some kind of a wrapper around it. If you're having trouble setting up Glype with Squid, check out my post on proxy.org: http://proxy.org/forum/bug-reports-suggestions/7164-glype-proxy-settings-do-not-work.html

Comment: i found how to make glype to talk to squid, the way you provided in your link doesn't work (i've tried it before commenting on your post)

Comment: Mateusz, did you get a way to completely get rid of Glype? We are trying to do the same thing i.e. get rid of Glype and get some proxy like Squid.